# PHP arrays inserts all values with 1 first before value 2?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

PHP is adding all values with 1 before the value 2. 
Like:

it's adding 1,10,11,100,110 before 2

How can I add 2 before 10?

I am looping inside folder, my code is like:

I got 19 slides; when I am printing the result is:

```
 - slide1
 - slide10
 - slide11
 - slide12
 - slide13
 - slide14
 - slide15
 - slide16
 - slide17
 - slide18
 - slide19
 - slide2
 - slide3
 - slide4
 - slide5
 - slide6
 - slide7
 - slide8
 - slide9
```

---

```
$slides = array();
foreach (glob($this->getProject($project_id)."/ppt/slides/*.xml") as $slide) {
    $slides[] = $slide;
}
return $slides;
```

Comment: It goes in alphabetical order, so 1, 10, 100 all go before 2. If you want them in the correct order, you should name them 001, 002, 003 ... 998, 999 and that will ensure that they rise by number

Comment: Its ceraintly possable to reorder how you require, but you will need to show the actual contents of the array (eh output from `var_dump($slides);`) for a proper answer

Comment: Also, if thats your actual code, the loop is pointless: `$slides = glob($this->getProject($project_id)."/ppt/slides/*.xml");`

Comment: [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) sorts the directory listing if `GLOB_NOSORT` option is not set. and this is the most sensible way a computer can sort a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is to use the natural sort: [natsort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natsort.php) or [natcasesort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php) (the case insensitive version of natural sort)

```
$slides = array();
foreach (glob($this->getProject($project_id)."/ppt/slides/*.xml") as $slide) {
    $slides[] = (string) $slide;
}

natsort($slides);

return $slides;
```

Comment: when i use this in test array with loop it is working. but not in my code. I am using already another functions to get slide name etc.

Comment: it's working when i use print_r before the return $slides, but i have a function like 'function getSlide($slide_id, $project_id)
      { 
       $slides = $this->getAllSlides($project_id);
          return $slides[$slide_id];
      }' and in there is it not working

Comment: why would you sort it there if you only return a single slide?

Comment: I have project, i am looping between all slide#.xml files. which i am adding to array. This array am i using for other functions to check one by one the content of the # file.

Comment: Let me understand.. the content you put in the question is the content of the method `getAllSlides` ? I don't understand where exactly it works and where it isn't

Comment: yes, the method getallslides is adding slides#.xml to array. with path like  ( [0] => convertables/Projecten/project/ppt/slides/slide1.xml [1] => convertables/Projecten/project/ppt/slides/slide10.xml [2] => convertables/Projecten/project/ppt/slides/slide11.xml [3] => convertables/Projecten/project/ppt/slides/slide12.xml [4] => convertables/Projecten/project/ppt/slides/slide2.xml [12] => convertables/Projecten/project/ppt/slides/slide3.xml [13] ....  ) , but i got 2 other methods like  function sizeOfSlides($size)
      {
         return sizeof($this->getAllSlides($size));
      }

Comment: and // getSlide
      function getSlide($slide_id, $project_id)
      { 
       $slides = $this->getAllSlides($project_id);
          return $slides[$slide_id];
      }     the getSlide($slide_id, $project_id) method  is used in many other functions

Comment: Can i put natsorterd(array) values into another  new array?

Comment: @TheJokerAeZ in `getAllSlides` function, replace `return $slides;` with `return array_values($slides);` This resets the array keys so your other functions will work as expected

Comment: Yeah, it worked today, it is strange:P i have accepted this answer. With the solution of steve!